# Array not storing values properly

Tags: swift, ios9, alamofire

I'm writing code that gets and and multiple image urls from an API and saves them into an array.

Here's the code:

```
for user in usersArray {
    usersN++
    let collab = user as! String
    let r = i
    let p = usersN       
    Alamofire.request(.GET, Constants.Path.rootUrl + "/api/users/?username=" + collab +  "&fields=image", headers: self.headers)
            .responseJSON { _,_, JSON in

        let array = JSON.value?.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary

        self.collabsArray.append(array.objectForKey("image") as! String)

        if usersN == usersArray.count {
            self.secImageUrls.append(self.collabsArray)
            self.collabsArray = [] 
        }

        if r == self.jsonFeeds.count {
            self.loadingStatus = "collabsPics"
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }   
    }
}
```

Now, usersArray often stores multiple usernames, so every collabsArray should store several urls. However, when I print out its content, it's always storing only one url, like if its content is being overwritten every time.

collabsArray is declared as:

```
var collabsArray = [String]()
```

Full function:

```
    func getCollabProfileImages(){

    var i = 0

    for feed in jsonFeeds {
        i++
        let feedType = feed["type"] as! Int

        if feedType == 1 {
           let usersArray : NSArray = feed["users"] as! NSArray

           var usersN = 0
           for user in usersArray {
             usersN++

             let collab = user as! String
             let r = i
             let p = usersN

            Alamofire.request(.GET, Constants.Path.rootUrl + "/api/users/?username=" + collab +  "&fields=image", headers: self.headers)
                    .responseJSON { _,_, JSON in


                            let array = JSON.value?.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary
                                                     self.collabsArray.append(array.objectForKey("image") as! String)

                            if usersN == usersArray.count {

                                self.secImageUrls.append(self.collabsArray)
                                self.collabsArray = []

                            }

                            if r == self.jsonFeeds.count {

                                self.loadingStatus = "collabsPics"
                                self.tableView.reloadData()

                            }
                }
            }
        } else {

            self.secImageUrls.append(["nomm"])

            //print(self.secImageUrls)

            if i == self.jsonFeeds.count {

                self.loadingStatus = "collabsPics"
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks OK to me. How about places so break points to examine what's going on?

Comment: Please, provide full code without redundant details. Where `userN and `i` is defined? Why does `userN` not zeroed?

Comment: This code has all sorts of timing issues. `self.collabsArray = []` might be called before all the responses come back. Responses are not guaranteed to be returned in the order they're called.

Comment: I added the code for the full function @mixel

Comment: Isn't that called after it looped through all the elements of usersArray? @AaronBrager

Comment: @dpstart Yes, but not necessarily after all the requests have returned. Depends on how long each request takes. Your code might wipe out the array before all the data is added.

Comment: And how can I correct that? @AaronBrager